# How can we Migrate IBM Lab servers from my local VM's to IBM bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

Currently I have some IBM LAB servers which are deployed on local virtual machines. I want to migrate them to IBM Bluemix. Is it possible to take an image of them and upload it to IBM Bluemix or create a new server on IBM Bluemix with those images?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Pawan. I removed your contact phone number from the post because providing your phone number publicly can open you to unnecessary phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

Ashok: You can use the Openstack CLI http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/openstack.html and upload the image to Bluemix. Check openstack image create option from the list.